# Cogwheel icon on dock when using alt + tab

Tags: release-loki, plank, icons

In the Dock I can see all the icons for the applications I have open.
[image]
But there is just a icon with a cogwheel for some applications (Vivaldi, Intellij and Postman in this case) when I cycle through the open applications with `alt` + `tab`. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Vivaldi icon started working after a re-start. For Intellij I created a new `.desktop` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493011/2420986) and for Postman I created a `.desktop` file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Postman
Icon=/home/user/Postman/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Exec=/home/user/Postman/Postman %u
Comment=Postman Native App
Categories=Network; 
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=postman
```

Save the .desktop file in `/home/user/.local/share/applications/`

Comment: You should migrate the solution to this answer and then you can mark it as the accepted answer to help people who come here later :)

Comment: @MikeWild done ;)

Comment: @g3blvm, it's not quite done yet. You have to mark it as accepted and not upvote it.